# How can I define a function that applies the composition of three functions to a value?

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I've got the following question, and I have no idea where to start:

> Write a function
>
> ```
> trifecta :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (c -> d) -> a -> d
> ```
>
> that takes 3 functions and composes them into a function that takes a value and produces a value. When writing tests, include some that have all the types different.

How can I do that?

Comment: `foobar ab bc cd = cd . bc . ab`

Comment: Hint: you can compose functions that you received as parameters.

Comment: Or `(flip (.) .) . flip (.)`, if you're insane.

Comment: @DietrichEpp OH MY GOD (in a good way)

Comment: The asker says "lost as to what the question is asking", probably not seeking for the answers?

Comment: @Yosh actually OP hasn't asked anything, hence it's not possible to answer "it"

Comment: no its not, its a practice question

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever used [djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn)? It's a [theorem prover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) for intuitionistic propositional logic. In simple words, given a [simple type signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) it generates a Haskell expression that satisfies that type.

You can install djinn using the command `cabal install djinn`. After that run the `djinn` command line program:

```sh
$ djinn
Welcome to Djinn version 2011-07-23.
Type :h to get help.
Djinn> trifecta ? (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (c -> d) -> a -> d
trifecta :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (c -> d) -> a -> d
trifecta a b c d = c (b (a d))
```

As you can see, given the command to find a proof of the function `trifecta ? (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (c -> d) -> a -> d`, djinn came up with the solution:

```hs
trifecta :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (c -> d) -> a -> d
trifecta a b c d = c (b (a d))
```

Hopefully, if you use djinn you'll be able to find answers to trivial problems by yourself and by studying the output you should be able to grok the basic essence of functional programming.

Comment: after installing djinn how do u run it , by typing djinn on my command line , i get "command not found @Aadit M Shah

Comment: Make sure that the cabal bin directory is in your path environment variable. I'm currently away from my desktop hence you'll need to google how to do that on your OS.

Comment: I don't really see how djinn will help attain understanding. The human needs to learn to read types; showing how the computer can do it seems a little sideways.

Answer (score 1):

You are requested to write a function `trifecta` which accepts a function taking a value of type `a` returning a value of type `b`, written as `(a -> b)`, a function taking a value of type `b` and returning a value of type `c`, written as `(b -> c)`, and finally a function taking a value of type `c`, and returning a value of type `d`. If you apply those functions one after the other, you can see there is a way to get a value of type `d` from a value of type `a` by using all these three functions.

If you get the implementation of `trifecta` correct, this should work:

```
Prelude> trifecta show reverse read 15 :: Double
51.0
```

The value 15 is converted to a string (by `show`), then `reverse`d, obtaining "51", and finally converted to a floating point variable (by `read`). In this case, the type `a` is `Integer`, `b` is `String`, `c` is `String` and `d` is `Double`, so this is not solving the task of having *all* types different completely, as `b` and `c` are the same type.